# Why does a function pointer declaration need to know the types of the parameters and return value?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-construction, function-pointers, static-typing

Why does a function declaration in C need to know the types of the pointed-to-function's parameters and return value?

A pointer declaration in c is written as follows:

```
returnType ( *funcPtrName ) ( paramTypes )
```

For example `foo` below:

```
char my_func ( int x )
{
    ...
}


int main ()
{
    char ( *foo ) ( int );

    foo = my_func;

    foo( 2 );
}
```

When declaring a pointer to a value, the type is used to determine the size (in bytes) of one element. For example in `int* p`, the `int` tells the compiler that the elements pointed to by `p` are `sizeof( int )` apart. This information is used for pointer arithmetic.

However, a function pointer points to a single address and pointer arithmetic is not allowed.

So why is the extra information needed? Are the `returnType` and `paramTypes` included solely for the purpose of supporting error checking by the compiler? (Eg. to alert the user when they assign a function whose type doesn't match).

Comment: What is a type system, if not *extra information included solely for the purpose of supporting error checking by the compiler*?

Comment: Exactly the same reason that function prototypes exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several reasons. Let’s consider the return value first.

Suppose a program contains the code `y = f(x);`. After calling `f`, the compiler needs to get the value that `f` returned and assign it to `y`. Where does it get that value? In some systems, integer return values are passed in general registers and floating-point return values are passed in floating-point registers. So the compiler cannot know where the return value is unless it knows the type. Wide integers, such as `long long int`, might be passed in multiple registers. Small structures might be returned in registers, while large structures might be returned in memory, using a pointer to space the calling function provides and that it is required to pass to the called function as a hidden argument. The compiler needs to know the type to know how many bytes to get and where they are.

Similarly, the compiler needs to know where to put the arguments when it is calling a function. The first several integer arguments might be passed in general registers, while the first few floating-point arguments might be passed in floating-point registers. Additional arguments of either type might be pushed onto the stack.

Additionally, sometimes programmers might pass an integer expression where the function actually expects a floating-point argument, such as in `pow(x, 4)`. When the compiler knows the argument must be a floating-point argument, it can convert it to the expected type.

Another benefit is that, when the compiler knows the types, it can report an error if the argument does not match the expected type and cannot be implicitly converted to the expected type, and it can similarly report an error if the return type does not match.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the "extra information" you're asking about is mostly "for the purpose of supporting error checking by the compiler."

Function prototypes carry along argument type information so that the compiler can check that calls through the function pointer will have the correct arguments for the called function -- whatever it is.  That's the whole point of function prototypes -- to ensure that functions are called with the correct arguments.

If you're not interested in this (or if you're cheating and using function pointers that point to a variety of heterogenous functions, taking different numbers of arguments, and hoping everything works out), you can do that -- by simply leaving the parentheses empty, as in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1(int a, int b) { printf("f1(%d, %d)\n", a, b); }
int f2(double d) { printf("f2(%f)\n", d); }

int main()
{
    int (*allegedly_generic_function_pointer)();

    allegedly_generic_function_pointer = f1;
    (*allegedly_generic_function_pointer)(1, 2);
    allegedly_generic_function_pointer = f2;
    (*allegedly_generic_function_pointer)(3.4);
}
```

Here `allegedly_generic_function_pointer` is a pointer to a function taking unspecified arguments, and returning `int`.  ("Function taking unspecified arguments" was how all functions and function pointers were described in pre-ANSI C, before function prototypes were invented.)  As shown, you can use `allegedly_generic_function_pointer` to point to -- and call -- functions taking different arguments.  (Your compiler might give you various "helpful" warnings, though.)

So far I've only been talking about argument information.  The return type of the pointed-to function has a more vital purpose -- so the compiler can generate correct code for dealing with the return value at all.

(Why is the return type more vital than the argument types?  Well, when you call a function without a prototype in scope, the compiler assumes that the number and types of the expected arguments exactly match the number and types of the arguments you actually supplied in your call -- and the compiler obviously knows that, because the information is right in front of it as it's compiling the call.  But the only way it can know the return type of the called function is for that to have been explicitly specified in the function pointer type declaration.)

If you want a pointer to a function taking unspecified arguments *and* with an unspecified return type, that's one of the things that you simply can't do in C.  (Why would you want such a thing?  Ask me about the C interpreter I wrote once.)

Comment: Why would I want such a thing? What about the C interpreter you wrote once?